# MySQL: How do I join the same table multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, join, alias

I have three tables that are used within my query: `users`, `posts` and `swaps`.

Here's the structure of the tables.

Swaps: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwxe8.png

Posts: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6y1x.png

This is my current query that partially works:

```
"SELECT item_name, item_thumb, item_id, swap_item, swap_message, username
FROM users 
JOIN swaps ON swaps.sender_id = users.id
JOIN posts ON posts.item_id = swaps.product_id
WHERE seller_id = {$_SESSION['id']}"
```

Now the issue is that I've already joined the `item_id` from the `posts` table to the `product_id` in the `swaps` table.

I'd also like the join the column `swap_item` from the `swaps` table to the `item_id` within the `posts` table... If that makes sense?

I've tried using aliases to my best understanding but haven't had any luck.

Comment: are you tried `JOIN posts ON posts.item_id = swaps.product_id AND posts.item_id = swaps.swap_item` ?

Comment: I have indeed. There's nothing wrong with that query in a structural context, it just doesn't seem to work when I want to echo out the swaps.swap_item

Comment: but you have any row with these criteria on your DB? with the same value in `product_id`, `swap_item`  and `item_id` from `posts`?

Comment: Yes the swap_item and item_id references a product_id in the posts table

Comment: Give each instance of the table its own alias